# How to POST Iterate Array to webApi Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm trying to post my second array and get the id of item() to CreateItemset itemID so how to achieved that? this is what i did but it won't work

```
 postArray(){
        console.log(this.fg.value)
        this.microSvc.Post(this.fg.value)
        .subscribe((respo)=>{
          this.headerID = respo.id;
          for (const item of this.fg.value?.Info){
            item.id = this.headerID;
            console.log(item.id)
             this.microSvc.Post1(item)
             .subscribe((response)=>{
            for(const itemof this.fg.value?.SetItem){
              item.ItemId = this.detailsID
              this.microSvc.testing(serial).subscribe((res) =>{
                })
             }
              Swal.fire({
              title: 'Added Successfully!',
              icon: 'success',
              heightAuto: false,
              width: 400
             }).then((result) => {
             if (result.isConfirmed){
             }
             }) 
             })
             } 
           })
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not have a subscribe method called in another subscribe method, please use transformation + higher order mapping operator. I advice you to look into switchMap/mergeMap/exhaustMap/concatMap, and transformation operator like forkJoin/combineLatest.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. Use Rxjs ForkJoin. Then you can subscribe to it. Check how ForkJoin works in the official documentation for more info.

```
  const obs$: Array<Observable<Any>> = []
    
    for(value in values) {
      cont postMethod: Obsevable<any> = service.post(value)
      obs$.push(postMethod)
    }
    
    const result = forkJoin(obs$)
    
    result.subscribe();
```